# Check multiple checkbox in asp net, bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have found some answers about checking checkboxes in group but even if i copy this to mine side it wont works.
I have easy example of checkbox group.
Could any one explain me what am i doing wrong?

```js
var options = [];

$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(event) {

  var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
    val = $target.attr('data-value'),
    $inp = $target.find('input'),
    idx;

  if ((idx = options.indexOf(val)) > -1) {
    options.splice(idx, 1);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $inp.prop('checked', false)
    }, 0);
  } else {
    options.push(val);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $inp.prop('checked', true)
    }, 0);
  }

  $(event.target).blur();

  console.log(options);
  return false;
});

$("#checkAll").click(function() {
  $(".check").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
  <input id="btnZatwierdz" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="submit" value="Filtruj" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onserverclick="btnZatwierdzClick" runat="server"></input>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1">
        <input id="CheckboxHunting" type="checkbox" runat="server" />&nbsp;
        Hunting
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabindex="-1">
        <input id="CheckboxFarming" type="checkbox" runat="server" />&nbsp;
        Farming
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1">
        <input id="checkAll" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;
        Hunting
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="check" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1">
            <input id="Checkbox2" name="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" runat="server" />&nbsp;
            Hunting
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="check" data-value="option2" tabindex="-1">
            <input id="Checkbox3" name="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" runat="server" />&nbsp;
            Farming
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Try tell us what you want to happen with the checkbox

Comment: I want to check all checkbox in a group by one checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("li").find("input[id^='Checkbox']").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

This will take the closest `li` of `$("#checkAll")` and then find all `inputs` that starts with `Checkbox` (`id^='Checkbox'`)

```js
var options = [];

$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(event) {

  var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
    val = $target.attr('data-value'),
    $inp = $target.find('input'),
    idx;

  if ((idx = options.indexOf(val)) > -1) {
    options.splice(idx, 1);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $inp.prop('checked', false)
    }, 0);
  } else {
    options.push(val);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $inp.prop('checked', true)
    }, 0);
  }

  $(event.target).blur();

  console.log(options);
  return false;
});

$("#checkAll").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("li").find("input[id^='Checkbox']").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
  <input id="btnZatwierdz" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="submit" value="Filtruj" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onserverclick="btnZatwierdzClick" runat="server"></input>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1">
        <input id="CheckboxHunting" type="checkbox" runat="server" />&nbsp; Hunting
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabindex="-1">
        <input id="CheckboxFarming" type="checkbox" runat="server" />&nbsp; Farming
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1">
        <input id="checkAll" type="checkbox" />&nbsp; Hunting
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="check" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1">
            <input id="Checkbox2" name="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" runat="server" />&nbsp; Hunting
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="check" data-value="option2" tabindex="-1">
            <input id="Checkbox3" name="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" runat="server" />&nbsp; Farming
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No i dont get any errors. I think the problem is with JavaScript because your solution should work..